# Linode VPS Capabilities

Tags: vps, linode

I have no experience with VPS's. Over the past year or two I've been getting more and more into web development, as a hobby and for work. I'm currently managing one wordpress site, a codeigniter app, a node.js/mongodb app, and various other personal projects. They are currently all hosted seperately (misc LAMP hosting, heroku, etc.).

I'm looking for a solution that will enable me to do the following:

- Host Static/PHP Sites/Apps (so a LAMP stack)
- Node.js/MongoDB/Redis
- capable of other stacks (django/yesod/RoR/etc.)

Would a Linode VPS be capable of handling all of this? None of these sites get large amounts of traffic. The web apps are private, business management apps, used by 2-10 people at a time. The public sites are small business websites and my portfolio. I would like to be able to host future work on the same VPS as well (same types of small sites/apps).

I have no experience managing multiple domains on the same server. Is this easily done (or possible) with a single Linode VPS?

*EDIT*
I'm looking at the Linode 512MB/1GB VPS's, $20/$40 respectively.

Comment: Absolutely , your best choice .

Comment: "Yes" to all of your questions.  NOTE: Please don't limit your search to Linode - there are lots of other good alternatives, competitively priced.  I guess the main things are 1) make sure you have command-line "root" access (not just a CPanel), 2) sufficient disk, RAM and CPU and 3) decent technical support.  I'm very, very happy with my VPS: www.webkeepers.com

Comment: Thanks, I will be going with Linode then. ArchLinux is a huge plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course.

Especially after the [massive](https://blog.linode.com/2013/03/07/linode-nextgen-the-network/) [Linode](https://blog.linode.com/2013/03/18/linode-nextgen-the-hardware/) [NextGen](https://blog.linode.com/2013/04/09/linode-nextgen-ram-upgrade/) [upgrades](https://blog.linode.com/2013/07/25/storage-space-doubled/), a Linode VPS can easily handle this kind of workload.  Since it's a VPS and not merely shared hosting, you get root access and therefore full control over the system.

In addition, Linode includes features such as advanced disk image management that allows you to clone and resize disk images as required and quickly boot into different images, as well as an [out-of-band](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management) shell that allows direct access to the server's console in the event you cannot access it via SSH.  A Linode 1024 (1GB) plan is more than enough for this sort of workload.

There are lots of different VPS providers out there.  [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/servers/) is very expensive but probably has the highest level of reliability (100% uptime SLA with 5% refund per 30 minutes downtime) and outstanding "Fanatical Support".  For less critical needs, there are loads of smaller VPS providers that offer cheap rates, but often with only minimal resources and fewer features.  Some provide super-fast SSD storage for disk-intensive applications.  You should shop around and do your research so that you find a VPS provider that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you may look into a shared hoisting plan on a reputed hosting companies like hostgator since there isn't much traffic.I also suggest you also buy a cpanel for managing tools.Cpanel has a web interface with which you can control every tool using your mouse & keyboard.

On the other hand linode has a CLI interface and their support expects you to have some descent knowledge about managing VPS servers.